# Change colour of DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have the following code to add a checkbox column to my grid..

```
    Dim excludeColumn As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
    With excludeColumn
        .Name = "(excl)"
        .DataPropertyName = "exclude"
        .Width = 300
        .Visible = True
        .DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.LightBlue
    End With
    .Columns.Add(excludeColumn)
```

Why doesn't the colour of the `DefaultCellStyle` property change as required above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the `.BackColor` property. `.ForeColor` changes the text color which isn't present on a checkbox column.

Comment: This is fine in the datagridview definition when creating the table - but when I come to change the colour 'on-the-fly'....ie.

dataGridView_Events.Item(Excludecolumn, p).Style.BackColor = Color.LightBlue

this doesnt work... what am I doing wrong here...?

Comment: Possibly a reference issue. I think you should have used `dataGridView_Events.Item("(excl)", p).Style.BackColor = Color.LightBlue` instead. `DataGridView1.Item(1, 4).Style.BackColor = Color.Blue` works just fine for me where 1 is the column number and 4 is just a random row (p in your comment).

Comment: The reference is a CONST identifier for the column and used successfully throughout the rest of my project.
I have sorted it though.... I have transferred the code to the Paint() event for the grid control and all works as expected... Thanks for your input

Comment: I was under the impression when referring to items in a DGV that columns must be used either by number or their name property.